# Trying to remove an entire object from a linkedlist based on a specific bit of data in the lisy

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, linked-list

I am really struggling with something that should seem super simple but I can't get it to work.

I have a linkedlist looking something like this:

- ID   FirstName   LastName    Score
- 1    Dave        Davison     5
- 2    Jeff        Jeffison    1
- 3    Brian       Brianson    3

I am trying to get a user to input a value for the ID field, and then delete the whole object.

When I do this it deletes the object based on the array ID (so if they input 1 it removes the second object)

`System.out.println("Please enter an ID number to remove");  int id = scanner.nextInt(); students.remove(id);`

I have tried everything Mr Google would help me with but it varied from not working at all, to throwing errors.  This has to be something simple I am missing yea?

Comment: `students.remove(id-1);` *should* work (zero-indexed), but of course, only *once* if you think about it ;)

Comment: That only works if the ID never misses a number yea? 

(hence the only works once line right?)